# Setting separate usb cards for output and input on Raspbian Jesse

Tags: raspbian, usb

I'm a newbie. I have a separate usb for sound output and sound input(mic). How do I configure Raspbian Jessie to default to them?

Answer (score -1):

refer to Pulse audio [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) and Debian pulseaudio-related [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio). Raspbian is a Debian-style system, so it will work for you